# Simple Cubic Polynomial not Yielding Expected Results

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

So I've got this beautiful little piece of math, $n$ in this formula can be substituted with any non-negative number between 1 and 100.

$$
\frac65 n^3 - 15n^2+100n-140
$$

The expected results are kind of as follows...

- $n = 1 \to 9$
- $n = 2 \to 48$
- $n = 3 \to 39$
- $n = 4 \to 39$

The results I got after plugging in the respective values are such.

- $n = 1 \to -54$
- $n = 2 \to 10$
- $n = 3 \to 57$
- $n = 4 \to 97$

What am I not doing right? How do I figure out where the error is?

Included now are graphs of the expected results according to the person who first found this formula within a game. The formula I am posting about is represented in these graphs by the line with the color purple.

**Graph of expected results**
[image: Graph of expected results]

**Graph of expected results, ratio of n to "level" cubed**
[image: Graph of expected results, ratio of n to "level" cubed]

Comment: The actual values I got were $1\to-53.8,2\to9.6,3\to57.4,4\to96.8$

Comment: So, please explain where your expected results come from?

Comment: - This is nothing to do with linear, it is a *cubic polynomial*, please change the title.
- The results you quote are incorrect, they should be $-53.8,9.6,57.4,96.8$.
- Not clear what you want us to do about it, since you are not explaining anything about where the original formula came from nor why should the results be as you expect

Comment: Agreed! That's what I got as well in all my tests, even whilst changing the order of operations. However, that formula was datamined from a game in which the expected results are what you get from it. I'm not sure whether or if my calculations are wrong.

Comment: @RushabhMehta these agree with what I am seeing as well...

Comment: i would want to see what does that formula represent and also what it looks like. Also the 2nd graph is not clear what you are plotting -- is it $p(n)/n^3$?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define a cubic polynomial
$$
p(n) = an^3+bn^2+cn+d
$$
satisfying $p(1)=9,p(2)=49,p(3)=p(4)=39$, there is a unique polynomial like that. You can construct the coefficients by solving the Vandermonde system
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 4 & 8\\
1 & 3 & 9 & 27 \\
1 & 4 & 16 & 64
\end{pmatrix}
\times 
\begin{pmatrix} d \\ c \\ b \\ a \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} 9 \\ 48 \\ 39 \\ 39 \end{pmatrix}
$$
which yields the solution
$$
\begin{pmatrix} d \\ c \\ b \\ a \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} -135 \\ 215.5 \\ -81 \\ 9.5 \end{pmatrix}
$$
and the corresponding polynomial
$$
p(n) = \frac{19}{2} n^3-81n^2+\frac{431}{2}n-135
$$
but this seems to have nothing to do with your polynomial.

Comment: Those numbers are way more in line with what I'm looking for! 1-4 respond absolutely correct, but past 4 the numbers are jumping faster than what was anticipated.